# How to initialize Notification in the Proximity alert

Tags: android, notifications, geolocation, location

Trying to notify the user when he passes by this location using Proximity Alert. I assigned resultIntent to Notification_Handler.class which creates notification,However when the user is near that location the Notification is not pushed,How to push the notification in this case ?

```
//This is android App 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    // resize map
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) (getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mapFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 1400;
    mapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
    //Notify if user near a location
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Notification_Handler.class);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,          resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    lm.addProximityAlert(21.422, 39.826, 5, -1, pendIntent);}
```

EDIT: this is Notification Handler class

```
    package app.historical_markers.historical_markers;


    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

    import app.historical_markers.historical_markers.Not_Signed_In.KSA_Map;


    public class Notification_Handler extends ActionBarActivity {
        final int notificationID = 1234;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert!!!");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, You are near this Marker!");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, KSA_Map.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(KSA_Map.class);

// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The units of the radius parameter in [LocationManager.addProximityAlert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is meters.  You have specified a value of 5.  That is too small.  The GPS is not that accurate and you have specified your lat/long to a precision of only about 10 meters.

Use a larger radius value, something like 100.  The code to create the `PendingIntent` is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks i will modify the radius , but my main concern is how to add notification in the proximity alert instead of starting another intent ?

Comment: The proximity alert will only cause the activity you specify, Notification_Handler in this case, to run.  If you want a notification to appear, you need to put code to generate it in Notification_Handler.  Are you saying that the activity runs, you have code there to post a notification, but the notification is not appearing?  If so, post the code in Notification_Handler that generates the notification.

Comment: i have edited the question and added notification handler class, is there any thing wrong with it ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code to build the notification.  Add a `Log` statement to the `onCreate()` method of `Notification_Handler` so you can confirm that it is getting called.

Comment: This is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for `Log`.  The output normally appears in a window of your IDE.  You can also use the logcat command as [described here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html). Search the Web for more examples and tutorials.